# I am trying to divide a window into portions with panels, but they all resize to one huge frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

```
import Sprites.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
public class Main {
public int Health = 100;
public int ArmourPt = 0;
public int Gold = 250;
public static JLabel Goldlbl = new JLabel("Gold:");
public static JLabel Healthlbl = new JLabel("Health:");
public static JLabel ArmourPtLbl = new JLabel("Armour Points");
public static JFrame MainWindow = new JFrame();
public static int CalcDamage(int Damage, int Armour){
    int ReturnDamage = Damage - Armour + Damage / Damage + Armour / Damage * Damage -                     Armour + Damage + 25 ;
    if(ReturnDamage < 0){
        ReturnDamage = 0;
    }
    return ReturnDamage;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MainWindow.setSize(1500, 700);
    MainWindow.setTitle("Ampventure");;

    JPanel MPanel = (JPanel)MainWindow.getContentPane();

    JPanel StatsPanel = new JPanel();
    StatsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
    StatsPanel.setSize(350, 450);
    StatsPanel.setLocation(0, 0);
    StatsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension (350, 450));
    MPanel.add(StatsPanel);

    JPanel InvPanel = new JPanel();
    InvPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
    InvPanel.setSize(350, 250);
    InvPanel.setLocation(0, 450);
    StatsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension (350, 250));
    MPanel.add(InvPanel);

    MainWindow.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

When executed this is SUPPOSED to make two panels off to the side and with different sizes adding up to the total Y and 350 X. Instead it just makes them all the same size and just makes a border around the window.

How do i get it to do this?

(EDIT) I have fixed the typo. and only the Stats Panel does what it's supposed to do.
ALSO I don't want to use a layout manager. I want to set and size everything myself.

Comment: The content pane probably has a layout manager by default. Try calling `MPanel.setLayout(null);` before adding components.

Comment: @user2839482 I updated my answer to match your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.  You are adding stats panel twice.

Also, you may want to set a layout manager.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

EDIT:  Response to your edits.
The content pane will default to Flow Layout as all panels do.  You need to set it to use a different layout manager or no layout manager if you want to set the size and location yourself.  I'd advise against that though, as your code will not be able to handle varying resolutions and screen sizes easily.

Here is information on coding without a layout manager.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: Thanks! I'd rather not use a layout manager. Things need to be in a precise position.

Comment: No, contentPanes always default to BorderLayout, not FlowLayout.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `GridBaglayout`

[GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)